# Check Duplication With the database asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, detailsview

I have a details view and a button, and when I click on the button, I want to check if the username is already in the database or not. I tried the below code but it goes to the else statement, even if the username exists.

Any help?

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    string query = "select Username from [Login]";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

    SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sqlda.Fill(dt);

    int RowCount = dt.Rows.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
    {
        Label13.Text = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        Label14.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Username"].ToString();

        if (Label13.Text == Label14.Text)
        {
            string message = "Username is Already Exists";

            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
            sb.Append("alert('");
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("')};");
            sb.Append("</script>");

            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "Successfully saved";

            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
            sb.Append("alert('");
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("')};");
            sb.Append("</script>");

            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
        }
    } 
}
```

Details view markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Username" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
           ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="283px" 
            style="margin-top: 0px; text-align: left;" 
           onitemupdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated" onitemdeleted="DetailsView1_ItemDeleted" 
           oniteminserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted" DefaultMode="Insert" 
           oniteminserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' 
                        ValidationGroup="1"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ForeColor="Red" 
                        ValidationGroup="1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>' ValidationGroup="1"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        ValidationGroup="1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserType" SortExpression="UserType">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserType") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString ="<%$ConnectionStrings: ConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UserType") %>' ValidationGroup="1">
                    <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>employee</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>doctor</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>student</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="DropDownList4" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                        InitialValue="--Select--" ValidationGroup="1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserType") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowInsertButton="True" ValidationGroup="1" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `dt.Rows[i]["Username"].ToString()` . Put debugger, and check both value.

Comment: Your sample has a lot of code which is not relevant for the question. Just show the method where you try to check the value in the database.

Comment: It seems while iterating over the data you are storing the last and one username in the Label14.Text. Therefore, it wont match.

Comment: Why don't you do this way `string query = "select Username from [Login] where Username ="+Label14.Text;` and get only that specific username instead of getting all the users from db.

Comment: Your code is wide open to a SQL Injection attack - use Parameterized Queries to prevent this: https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries

Comment: use 'string.Equals()' instead of  '=='

Comment: You are comparing the first user and it goes to else.  This code has has a lot of problems.

Comment: @Amit Kumar yes that is why I put the labels to make sure of the values if they are same or not

Comment: @Paparazzi so how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass username as parameter to Db.

```
  string query = "select Username from [Login] where Username=@username";
     var nameParam = new SqlParameter("username");
     nameParam.Value = Label13.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
```

It will fetch only records if username will exist in db.

Then Check it using rowCount.

```
if(RowCount> 0){
    //Username exist
}else {
    //Do other work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this way.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
string query = "select Username from [Login] WHERE Username='"+((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text+"'";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.HasRows())
{
// The username exist
}
```

Comment: Ok I tried the below code and I tested it with button and it worked, but know I want to assign it to the insert command of the detailsview. I tried to put it in DetailsView1_ItemInserting but in case of if statement it gives me the yellow error page with PK duplication, but in case of else statement is works fine. Any Help??

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string query = "select Username from [Login] where Username = '" + ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            if (dr.HasRows == true)
            { //error message here}
            else { //success message here }
            con.Close();